# Is there a name for "sts", "sks" and "sps" sounds found in words like "tastes", "tasks", and "wasps"?

Tags: pronunciation

Is there a name for "sts", "sks" and "sps" sounds found in words like "tastes", "tasks", and "wasps"?

I seem to remember someone telling me the name for it.

Comment: @Jim Duplicate? I think the question is quite specific and stands on its on.  Further, how would one map (search) my question to the question you assert is duplicated?

Comment: Hi Jamie, specificity and being able to stand on their own are independent of duplication.  The answer “consonant clusters” to the linked question is the answer to your question. And by having this closed as a a duplicate of that one will allow future visitors to find your question and be pointed to the answer.  It’s all good.

Comment: @Jim No, that ain't so. For a start the title question on that page doesn't match the question.  A dipthong is a single vowel whose realisation is a changing vowel that starts with one quality and ends with another. A consonant cluster is just two or more consonants next to each other. Another problem is that there is a specific term for clusters formed by a stop interupting two sibilants. These are unusual in terms of syllable structure because they involve a rise and then fall in sonority within the same syllable. Erm, can't remember what it is though!

Comment: @Jim For what its worth, the analagous term to diphthong would be ***affricate***..

Comment: Those particular final sequences are the ones that are most llikely to get smeared into a single long /s:/. It's very hard to pronounce clusters with a stop and a sibilant on either side, especially when the final sibilant is a suffix. What happens is that all of these clusters become a long single /s:/ at the end of a word. In speech; the spelling isn't affected. So, in ordinary rapid speech, the words would be pronounced /te:ss/, /tæss/, and /wass/.

Comment: @JohnLawler Not in my speech! I like the sound too much to avoid the opportunity. :)

Comment: Everybody is always very sure what they're pronouncing; but you might be surprised at what others hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consonant Cluster,
Consonant Sequence, or
Consonant Compound** may be the term.

> In linguistics, a **consonant cluster**, **consonant sequence** or **consonant compound** is a group of consonants which have no intervening vowel. In English, for example, the groups /spl/ and /ts/ are consonant clusters in the word *splits*.
>
> Some linguists argue that the term can only be properly applied to those consonant clusters that occur within one syllable. Others contend that the concept is more useful when it includes consonant sequences across syllable boundaries. According to the former definition, the longest consonant clusters in the word *extra* would be /ks/ and /tr/, whereas the latter allows /kstr/ or /kstʃr/ in some dialects.

[[Wikipedia]](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Consonant_cluster)